# Cannot publish a self-contained dotnet-core application due to NU1100

Tags: .net-core

I have ported a .net application to .netcore and want to publish it as a self-contained application. Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

<Path>\IPLauncher.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 (= 3.1.2)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
<Path>\IPLauncher.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64 (= 3.1.2)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
<Path>\IPLauncher.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 (= 3.1.2)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
  Restore failed in 179,65 ms for <Path>\IPLauncher.csproj.
```

In case it is important, my csproj-file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**Edited to add:** The weirdest part is that my colleague can publish a self-contained exe for the same project with identical configuration - so it seems to be some problem with my configuration.

Comment: Try `dotnet restore`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, `dotnet restore` does not report any errors, but the problem with `dotnet publish` remains the same.

Comment: Do you get the error when doing a publish without defining runtime `dotnet publish` ?

Comment: No, it works fine without -r. It also works fine if I use this: `dotnet publish -r win-x64 --no-self-contained`. I just can't create a self-contained exe.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried to reinstall .NET Core on your machine? Or clear NuGet caches?

Comment: I tried reinstalling, without any change. I can't find a Nuget directory under AppData\Local, so I guess I don't have a cache to clear.

Comment: My nuget cache is placed under `C:\Users\(user)\.nuget\packages`

Comment: Have you tried all of these at the same time: clearing NuGet cache,clearing NuGet download cache, delete `bin` and `obj` directories? Also, do you have custom feeds? Have you also compared your machine's NuGet.config vs. your coworkers?

Comment: Thank you very much - it works now! The issue was with the Nuget.config. Mine was (for whatever reason) referencing https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/. When I deleted the file, it was recreated referencing https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json instead and packages were resolved without problem. If you write an answer, I can assign the bounty to you.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like `nuget restore` command for your application can't restore some packages.

There are many reasons for that, but you can do basic research for determine why it's heppens. Here some tips:

1. Clear all NuGet caches `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`
2. Check if NuGet packages you trying to restore accessible from nuget.org website. Official nuget package manager website has different API's (v2/v3) so you must check you use latest version of API.
3. If you use NuGet package not from official portal - verify that NuGet server you use for restoring nuget packages is accessible.

These settings placed in default `nuget.config` file here: `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.config`

Note that if you using **custom nuget.config** for your project/solution it's overrides default nuget settings. This file can contains some settings that breaks restore command. So check it out first.